# How to generate a random string between the strings contained in a vector?

Tags: string, random, vector

Let's assume I have a vector of strings

```
vector<string> vec {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
string r;
```

I would like to have a random string (between the ones in vec) be generated and assigned to the string r.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can achieve this by writing the code to do it. What code have you written so far, and what problems are you having. Or, are you looking for someone else to do your homework assignment for you, for free?

Comment: Generate random number (i) with rand function in c++ between 0 and 3, then do strcut(r,vec[i]).

Comment: I hope you're not having a bad day @SamVarshavchik, I am just trying to learn, and there is no homework involved, I was trying to use an elegant 1-liner, so I was trying random_shuffle ( vec.begin(), vec.end(), r ); but I fail to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wide question, in terms of the amount of solution you can have and the amount of languages there are.
Lets talk generally, you can do something like that:
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i < vec.lenght; i++)
    {
        number = r(0,vec.lenght-i);
        string str = RemoveStringFromVectorAndShrinkIt(number);
        r += str;
    }